# Creating Android TV app to take HDMI port data and send it into my Custom App

Tags: java, android, service, android-tv, hdmi

Trying to create an Android TV app that will take input from the HDMI port and display it into a videoView.

I have loaded a library file of Realtek and created a stream service.
The hardware is **Realtek RTD1295**

Inside the MainFragment, the HDMI Manager is being created.
The onStart method is given as follows:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (preferences == null) {
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    }

    // halt startup if we don't have all needed permissions
    if (!checkPermissions()) {
        return;
    }

    if (hdmiSurfaceHolderCallback == null) {
        hdmiSurfaceHolderCallback = new HdmiSurfaceHolderCallback();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(hdmiSurfaceHolderCallback);
    }

    if (hdmiHotplugReceiver == null) {
        hdmiHotplugReceiver = new HdmiHotplugReceiver();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(hdmiHotplugReceiver, new IntentFilter(HDMIRxStatus.ACTION_HDMIRX_PLUGGED));
    }

    if (checkHdmiReadyHandler == null) {
        checkHdmiReadyHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                checkHdmiReady();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    if (hdmiRxManager == null) {
        hdmiRxManager = new RtkHDMIRxManager(); //Line 128 Of MainFragment
    }

    if (streamActivityReceiver == null) {
        streamActivityReceiver = new StreamActivityReceiver();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(streamActivityReceiver, new IntentFilter(STREAM_ACTIVITY_INTENT));
    }

    if (preferencesChangeListener == null) {
        preferencesChangeListener = new SharedPreferenceChangeListener();
        preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferencesChangeListener);
    }
}
```

There are two issues,

1. First run of the app is successful always. But from second time on
   wards it always throws the same error.
2. HDMI input is never detected even when the app runs for the first time.

The current Development is based on [this project](https://github.com/robbi5/instreamer)

The Error Log is as follows:

```
    Process: com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer, PID: 5757
                                                                      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer-1/base.apk", zip file"/data/app/com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "librealtek_runtime.so"at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                                          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                                          at com.realtek.hardware.RtkHDMIRxManager.<clinit>(RtkHDMIRxManager.java:30)
                                                                          at com.hydra.sid.hdmistreamer.layout.MainFragment.onStart(MainFragment.java:128)
                                                                          at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2244)
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1002)
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1130)
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1958)
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:163)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6259)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also developed this type of project and got same error in my situation this happed because the media box that i was using had not support realtek hardware so check your box support and use the Realtek  support  then your app will able to find realtek lib from system